# Fix my SQL Server blank screen

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, text-files, bulkinsert

Basically I've created a table in SQL Server:

```
  CREATE TABLE [Books]
(
     [store] int,
     [sgxg] int,
     [t] varchar(50),
     [movie] varchar(50),
     [year] int
);
```

but when I selected the rows from my table `books`, there was nothing there even though I refreshed it. 5 columns were created, but no data was inserted??

Comment: Add `ERRORFILE = 'file_name'` to see the errors during import. i guess, it is becuase your first row contains the  headers that cannot be inserted into the numeric columns. use the `FIRSTROW = 2` option to skip the first row

Comment: @cha hey sir I still can't bulk insert for reason, it worked on other computer someone just emailed me. So is it something wrong my sql server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE [Books]
(
     [store] int,
     [sgxg] int,
     [t] varchar(50),
     [movie] varchar(50),
     [year] int
);
```

Your procedure is *almost* correct.  Try this:

```
CREATE PROC [InsertBooks]
AS
BEGIN
  BULK INSERT [Books] 
  FROM 'C:\Users\dachen\workspace\612Lab3(XMLFinalVersion)\books.txt'
  WITH (
    FIRSTROW=2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR=',',
    ROWTERMINATOR='\n'
  )
END;
```

Execute the procedure as follows:

```
EXECUTE [InsertBooks];
```

View the data inserted:

```
SELECT * FROM [Books]
```

Comment: Not sure why you took all that other useful information out of your question.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: It's okay to anonymize, but critical information that makes the answer useful should stay.  For instance, anonymize the field names, the name of the data file, and the data.

Comment: Well, it depends on what you want.  You could run all the statements together, if you like - `CREATE TABLE...` Followed by `CREATE PROCEDURE...` followed by `EXECUTE...` followed by `SELECT...`, but what most would probably is to run the `CREATE TABLE...` and `CREATE PROCEDURE` only once, and then execute the stored procedure as needed with a different query.

Comment: so I can put that EXECUTE [InsertBooks]; right after end in the procedure?

Comment: sir it's still blank, I've sent my latest screenshot